# Automated database tracking of Undelivr email in ColdFusion?

Tags: email, coldfusion, tracking, cfmail

Given there is a "FAILTO=''" option for cfmail, triggering an email to be sent to that email if the email didn't get delivered...

Is there a way to somehow assign an ID or tracking # to an email, store it in a database with that ID... then update the status of that email if it fails?

I'd like to track bouncebacks... preferably WITHOUT sending the FAILTO to a POP3 or IMAP and then checking it with cfimap...

Is there any alternate way of handling this?

Maybe an event gateway that is triggered upon email failure?

UPDATE: I've decided to take a different approach, utilizing the sendgrid API.
I'm hoping that lends me with a few more tools than CF offers.

Comment: If you want to track bouncebacks properly it gets very complicated not just to get the bounces back in a useful way but to also analyze them to determine if they are automated message, soft, hard, temporary, etc. I highly recommend an existing product for this purpose. My company uses Zrinity which is also an optimized sending server but there are many products out there for bounce back tracking/management.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The short answer to your question is unfortunately no.

A longer version with a possible solution:
The failTo email address populates the return-path in the email header, this then 'should' be used by mail servers for bounce backs (however see - http://www.bennadel.com/blog/1899-GMail-Seems-To-Ignore-The-Return-Path-Header-Defined-By-The-CFMail-FailTo-Attribute.htm  for an example where it doesn't)

So you are going to need to monitor an Imap or pop account to see your mails, however you can set up an event gateway to monitor this, with detailed instructions here - http://www.alagad.com/documentation/imapGateway/ImapWatcher%20Gateway%20Documentation.pdf

What you're left with is needing to identify which mail matches which bounceback, when I've done something similar in the past I used unique id's for the failTo email addresses at a domain I owned. If you set that up and then use your listener cfc to look for the id in the return-path.

So your sending code would work along the lines of:

- Generate unique id
- Send mail
- Add row to database with unique id

Your listener.cfc would then need to inspect the email returned and if it finds the unique id update the row with whatever information that you're after.

Hope that that at least helps even if you'll need to set up some other bits.

Comment: Thank you, this was most helpful.
You answered my question very precise.

I think I will use my sendgrid account.
I'm thinking I can use their API to do this.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a directly watcher on the undelivr folder to log the failed emails, only really a solution if its own server and not a shared server though.

Comment: The email is only copied to undelivr if there's something wrong with it preventing CF from sending it.  Once it's out in the wild, anything can happen to it (bounce back because the recipient's inbox is full for example), CF doesn't check for that, once it's out the spool and off to your smtp server it's sent.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know once it leave the spool and is off to your SMTP server CF assume it's been sent correctly.

The email will trickle down the chain of SMTP servers/relays and if anything happen the only instruction they have is to bounce it back to the from address or failto address if present.  CF isn't listening at this point so it can't respond.

We use an external tool called Glock email processor to handle exceptions. It's not free, but works pretty well.  You can find it here: http://www.glocksoft.com/email-processor/

You need to configure it to check the failto address and from there you can take many actions.  I got it setup as a three strikes system.

Email address bounce, I increment a counter in my email table, at 3 I deactivate that email from the system.

Nothing you can't do yourself with cfpop though.